# Given a DVR and elements of pairwise distinct orders, the sum is nonzero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

https://amathew.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/totally-ramified-extensions/
In the above post one can find the following statement:

> Given a DVR and elements of pairwise distinct orders, the sum is nonzero.

By order he means valuation.
I could not find a proof of the above. For $2$ elements it is obvious. I tried induction but could not make it work.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102044/how-do-i-compute-the-discrete-valuation-of-the-sum-of-two-elements

This might help for the induction step I assume?

Comment: Think about how it works for prime numbers and the integers. If $p$ is a prime, and you add together any finite number of integers, each divisible by a different power of $p$, then the sum is divisible by the smallest power of $p$ dividing any of the terms, so it isn't zero. Now, generalize that argument.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments and answer that have been posted, mathemather?

Comment: @PaulK your link answers the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the intuition.